# $.each is only iterating through the last item in my array...Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I am trying to take an array from my DB, then target specific items in that array, put it into some HTML and have it render in the browser. In my code, the `alert(v.displayName)` will iterate through all the 'displayName' in my collection. However, when i put it into html elements, it only prints out the last item in my array. If I put return false `$('.commentsForTheWin')` then it will only print out the first item in my array.

```
$(function() {
    $('.commentsInit').click(function() {
        var uniCommID = $(this).attr("value");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/comments"
        }).success(function(users) {
            $.each(users, function(i, v) {
                alert(v.displayName);
                var b = '<div class="red">' +
                    '<div>' +
                    '<span>' +
                    i + " : " + v.username +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span>' +
                    " hello" +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span>' +
                    "45 pts" +
                    '</span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $('.commentsForTheWin').html(b);
            });
            $('.hideOnLoad:contains(' + uniCommID + ')').toggle("slow");
        })
    })
});
```

I am guessing its not liking that I am putting it in .html? However .text doesn't change it either. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us a sample of "users"

Comment: you need to append the data instead of simply overwriting the HTML every time `$.each()` is called

Comment: html() will override the existing details. Use append()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises as `.html()` overwrites the existing content, thus you are getting content added by last iteration.

You need to to use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `.html()` and [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove existing content.

```
//Remove the content before iteration
$('.commentsForTheWin').empty();

$.each(users, function (i, v) {
    ...
    //append new content
    $('.commentsForTheWin').append(b);
});
```

---

Another approach is to create a complete HTML string then use `.html()`

```
var htmlContent = '';
$.each(users, function (i, v) {
    ...
    //append new content
    htmlContent += b;

});
$('.commentsForTheWin').html(b);
```

Comment: He could also use html() but he has to initialize the b variable to a string and after that use the + operator to concatenate each $.each iteration, wrote this here just so there's a full range of responses

Comment: This fixed everything! Thank you! I will accept answer after 4 mins is up

Answer (score 2):

use `append()` instead:

```
 $('.commentsForTheWin').append(b);
```

`.html()` overwrites everything within the selector element.

Better way to create your html in loop and put them inside when you get all:

```js
var b='';
$.each(users, function(i, v) {
  b += '<div class="red">' +
    '<div>' +
    '<span>' +
    i + " : " + v.username +
    '</span>' +
    '<span>' +
    " hello" +
    '</span>' +
    '<span>' +
    "45 pts" +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
});
$('.commentsForTheWin').html(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()`, because by `.html()` in every iterate you overwrite the existing content in `commentsForTheWin` element.